# Authenticate a user from via a widget using Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

**Context**:

I am currently working on an embeddable widget, something akin to Intercom or
Hotjar, and have the need to authenticate users. Thus far, I got away with
using Passwordless authentication using Firebase auth but users complain that
it's a high friction process, and they'd rather not do it at all. The ideal
authentication solution would be to let users use their Google or Facebook
account and authenticate via OAuth2.

**Problem**:

Firebase Auth restricts authenticating via 3rd party auth providers if the
domain the user authenticates via is not whitelisted in the authorized domains
list. So if the user puts the code in abc.com, and tries to auth via Google
firebase rejects it because abc.com is not in the whitelist. Whitelisting the
domain of every client is unorthodox. I feel like the way I'm approaching it
is wrong because I can't correctly build up a mental model of how this would
work out. Technically cookies, sessions, etc. are pointless.

**Question**:

How would I go about providing the ability to let users authenticate via 3rd
party auth providers? Is this even technically possible?

**Potential Solutions**:

- Host the widget at the main app in a dynamic route (the website where the user
  would get the widget's code) and render this route as an iframe in the
  client's website. (ex: /widgets/{widgetID} would have the widget). I don't
  want to do this really because iframes are a serious pain but this sounds like
  the most feasible.

I'd like to know more/better solutions to address this particular situation.
It doesn't matter even if it's from a different cloud provider or a different
authentication service. **The goal is to authenticate the user from the widget
ideally via a 3rd party auth provider like Google.**

EDIT: This is the error that I currently receive:

```js
widget.js:2 auth/unauthorized-domain This domain (xyz.com) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.
```

Comment: AFIK domain [whitelist](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400741.) on Firebase Auth only affects to the redirections URLs and not restrict the domains that  can access to the login.

Is your consent screen marked as [internal only](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#general-verification-process)? if you application is marked as internal this setting prevents that users with other domains use google sign in method.

Comment: @JanHernandez Say I've added abc.com to the whitelist, my widget is in xyz.com and I try to authenticate a user via Google using a popup in xyz.com, then I caught a firebase error saying that the domain isn't authorized, what's the reason for this?

Comment: I added the error message that I received to the post

Comment: Is your domain `xyz.com` in `Autorized domains` as the error message mention and you verified the domain as is mentioned in this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/show-custom-domain)? 

both steps are mandatory to use your google sign in method with different domains

Comment: It's not, and that's the point, to authenticate a user via a domain that is not listed in the authorized domains list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use case, you need to verify the domain ownership `xyz.com` by following this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain)

After that you need to add `xyz.com`to Authorized domains your, as the error message mentioned.

```
Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.
```

For more information please check this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/show-custom-domain)

Is not possible enable Google Sign In by using a domain unverified or unauthorized, this is to protect the access to your sites/projects by restricting the usage of the Firebase/Google credentials only for configured domains.

There is no way to disable this setting, Google sign in uses [Oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/) as authentication framework

Comment: I established this fact and made the post in order to find a workaround or a solution that would allow me to authenticate a user in some way using Google Auth like the examples from the potential solutions section.